# android screen size resoulution

Tags: android, xml, screen-size

I have made an app for the screen size resoulution 480x800px(I have all my layouts and ImageButtons in the drawable-hdpi folder and I have used dp instead of px), in the xml I used layout_marginLeft and marginTop to place all the buttons and everything.. When i run my app in the emulator on 480x800 it is perfect, but if i change the screen size and resoulution all buttons changes place and size on the screen. I am very frustrated cause i have no idea what to do to make it fit all screen sizes and resoulutions what so ever? Any tips?

What different sizes should i use in different folders? I have 480x800 in hdpi, what should i have in xhdpi?

Comment: you can create different layouts for different screen sizes....

Comment: maybe use linear layout?

Comment: if you show your layout, we may be able to help...

Comment: go to developer.android.com and read the articles on screen sizes. Then you try to develop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to maintain different layouts for different screens. For example:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Add this one in manifest.xml

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For best UI design, you should  maintain Relative layout instead of LinearLayout.

See this:

For example: you want to display one image.. Then, now you need to maintain the same image in different sizes for different screens.

```
36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density
```

3:4:6:8 scaling ratio

Comment: What different sizes in different folders should I save the images in?

Comment: @user1734802 - you should see the xdpi, hdpi, mdpi, and ldpi folders.. YOur images of different sizes should be saved there. Also, create different sized xml layouts..

Comment: For example: you want to display one image.. Then, now you need to maintain the same image in different sizes for different screens.
    36x36 for low-density
    48x48 for medium-density
    72x72 for high-density
    96x96 for extra high-density
 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio

Answer (score 5):

Its simple actually.You just need to add layouts for different sizes and let android choose what suits best.
eg-layout-small(for small screens),layout-large(for large screens) etc.Also put images on all three folders(drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi) so that android can choose according to the screen size.
Just refer http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html.

Answer (score 3):

I would really appreciate if I could see some code.

If you use `RelativeLayout` with attributes like `android:layout_below` and margins in dp (density pixels) e.g. `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` it should work just fine.

[You can see an example here.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/)

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html. Check the link's.